# Repair ubuntu desktop after update

Tags: apt, unity, package-management, dependencies, lightdm

I have blank screen after ubuntu(16.04) update and I am trying to fix that with

```
 apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

but I have unmet dependencies

> gnupg : Breaks: python-apt (<= 1.1.0~beta4) but 1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
>    ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed

I tried

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get upgrade
```

how can I resolve that dependency without removing gnupg because as far as I remember if I delete that I can break system packages

Comment: A quick look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-apt shows your sources are *outdated*, you have invalid sources, or are using a mirror that is *outdated* (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).  I'd `apt-cache policy python-apt` and investigate your source(s) for it. FYI: you didn't provide architecture so I assumed amd64/i386 so your messages should say 1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.8.  Something you've added from 3rd party sources could also be your issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)